# Java Regarding Object Scope and Modification on the Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, scope

I have a question regarding I guess the scope of objects and whether or not the values the object holds would be changed under certain conditions.
For example, I have made a class in which I need to contruct more than 1 instance of the object, but these instances need to be used and modified throughout the programm and no new instances should be made after the first are made (I don't know what design pattern this would be following if any). The way I have designed the object is something similar to the following:

```
//basic constructor class
public class MyObject {

private String var1;
private int var2;
private boolean vr3

public MyObject(String param1, int param2, boolean param3) {
    var1 = param1;
    var2 = param2;
    var3 = param3;
}

//getter and setter methods

}

//in main class
Map<String, MyObject> myObjects = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
```

on the start of my program, I search through some files to construct new MyObject objects then put them in the HashMap and that is the only time a new MyObject should be created. So throughout the program, I get the objects in the HashMap by getting the value that matches the String key, and once I have that object, I may do things to it using the different setter methods like below:

```
MyObject object1 = MyObjects.get("anObject");
```

object1.setVar1("This is the objects new var1 string value");

And that code above should change the string value in the object that is in the HashMap under the key "anObject". But I am wondering that should this also work for things like Lists? like say I had a list as one of the values in the object, and if I got that object from the HashMap, and called something like:

```
object1.getList().add("new value in the object1 list");
```

would that add the value to the object in the hashMap? I am wondering this because since I called: 
MyObject object1 = MyObjects.get("anObject");
it seems like it could be creating a new instance of that class or just copying it over and that any changes to that object1 object wont be made to the object in the HashMap.

Am I correct that the changes made to any values to the object gotten form the HashMap will be put back to the object in the HashMap?
Sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: yes, because they are the same object.  You are just passing references around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is pass by value, however `MyObject` is a reference and this is passed by value.

This means every copy of a reference to your Object is the same object and wherever you attempt to change it, the same object will be changed.

The object itself will only be copied when you copy it, not implicitly.

Comment: ok good to hear! I am mad at my self that I wasn't positive on this! I am trying to start coding with more of an OO approach, as I din't before. Thanks for the good answer!

Comment: Note: C++ doesn't do this in the same way.  It has default copy constructors and if you assign "MyObject o = x;` this will copy the values of `x` into another object `o`.  In Java, `MyObject` is implicitly just a reference, why? because there is no other option.

Comment: I have one more question and I might as well ask it here. If I had a void delete() method in the object that is in the HashMap, and if when this method was called, it removed itself from the hashmap, would this be legal? like: myObject.delete(); would be myObjects.remove("anObject");

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: any changes made to the internals of the object that you retrieve from the HashMap will be changed in the HashMap, as when you retrieve an object from any data structure, you are actually getting a pointer to an object, so the HashMap and the pointer you get back both point to the same object data.  The only times when this is different is if you are storing primitives (like int, double, float, etc.) or if you reconstruct the object you have received from the HashMap.